# fund raising themometer generator

Tags: html

I'm looking for a simple gadget/widget to add to my site.  It should allow me to display some sort of themometer showing funds raisted.

Can someone please recommend a good one?

Comment: Post this as a job on some freelance site like vworker.com and someone will do it for $5.

Comment: I don't think this makes for a good stackoverflow question. But it would be perfect for chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: in which part of the chat.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Georg Please don't refer people to the chat about questions and don't refer to other site when you don't know about what question fit in them. This question is totally off-topic and will be instantly closed if it's asked on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Probably your own room, "I need a fund raising widget", but I'm not sure how well that works at the moment. Creating one yourself using CSS is pretty simple as well: pupungbp.erastica.com/css/creating-progress-bar-with-css

Comment: @HoLyVieR: You're right. I just checked the first few questions and saw a *What's the best \*\*\*\*\*\*\*?* and assumed it would fit. I removed my previous comment. Still, I think this question would fit in the chat, see Jeff's router chatroom for example: http://chat.superuser.com/rooms/19/recommend-me-a-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for:

http://www.fundraiserinsight.org/libs/thermometer.php?current=500&max=1000

Answer (score 1):

[ChipIn](http://www.chipin.com/) is a free and popular fund raising widget.

http://www.chipin.com

Comment: ChipIn wants a paypal account.  I want to be able to freely set the min max and current values.